# GroupBy ignores orderBy when using leftjoin

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables.

`rooms` with `id`, `title`
`chats` with `id`, `content`, `room_id`, `created_at`

My goal is fetch `rooms` and orderBy `created_at` of `chats` in `desc` mode. It's a simple query, yet it's giving a headache in Laravel. I cannot use the eloquent ORM way and do a sort in `with` method. Thus, I had to use a `join`.

My query looks like this:

`$items = $items->select("rooms.*")->join("chats", "chats.room_id", "=", "rooms.id")->orderBy("chats.created_at", "desc")->groupBy('rooms.id');`

Result:

1. I'm getting the data without any order for `created_at`.
2. removing `groupBy` will result in a correct order, but because it's missing the `groupby`, the room will exist as much as it has `chats`. So it's not a great approach.

What am I missing? If i need to include other information, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: I've used a leftJoin and a join, both same result, although I think it's more logical to use leftJoin in this context, as I'm only interested in the left table `rooms`.

Comment: After grouping by the column none other column makes sense in ordering - aggregate function from such column makes sense only.

Comment: Can you please give an example approach?

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comment said, I should use an `aggregate` function in the query while using a groupby function. Basically, it will look like this

```php
$items = $items->select("rooms.*")
->selectRaw("max(chats.created_at) as latest_created_at")
->join("chats", "chats.room_id", "=", "rooms.id")
->orderBy("latest_created_at", "desc")
->groupBy('rooms.id');
```

Then, it will be ordered correctly. I'll leave the thread, maybe someone will use the same clumsy search keywords as mine and see this question :)